# Eclipse Juno typing lag on OS X Lion

Tags: eclipse, macos, editor, lag

this is mostly to raise awareness and promote certain bugs on the Eclipse team I guess.

Env:

- MacOSX 10.7.4 
  -Eclipse Juno final 64bit
- Core2Duo MacBookPro 2009
- SSD main HD.
- Java 6 SDK used (latest revision from Apple Update)

It seems on quite large Java source files (1-2klines), typing of any code anywhere is causing

- 1) Extreme CPU load (peaks)
- 2) Quite a lag on typing

I have tried to disable autocomplete, line printing, and other features, reduce or increase memory settings on eclipse.ini, but nothing resolved it.

Anyone else with the same problem?

Eclipse Bugzilla search [query](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=typing%20lag).

Comment: Do you have any additional eclipse plugins installed other than the defaults available from Juno?

Comment: I have (had- reverted to Indigo for now) the latest subclipse plugin. thats the only one. :/

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this on Windows 7 as well.  I checked my task manager and eclipse was paging out from memory.  Edit the `eclipse.ini` file (found right next to the eclipse executable).  I up the memory limit to:

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx2048m
```

Depending on how much RAM you machine has, you can first try

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

I have 16GB of RAM so I went higher.

It helped me, hopefully it works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input...

I'm pretty sure that much of what you're seeing is caused by

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=389019

This was causing us to execute some very heavy-weight code on every character. It's been fixed (as of 2012-09-20) and will be available in 4.2.2. Should you want to test to see if this solves your issue it's available in any 'M' build later than that date.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The lag goes away if I close console window (doesn't work anyway?!) and restart eclipse.

My run/debug configuration windows and subclipse commit/update windows aren't working either.

Comment: At the time being - I am still using indigo! I am trying to find a related bug on their BugZila and submit it. I hope that their going to address the issue in an upcoming SR1 release. I am wondering though, why more people did not complain quick enough about it, slow update rates? Who knows! Thanks for confirming!

Comment: I've noticed that the issues only (mostly?) appear after upgrading. Installing a fresh copy of eclipse 4 does not seem to give these problems.